# How can template functions know size when size info is not explicitly stated?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template<size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
void f(const array<array<int, COLS>, ROWS>& arr)
{
   for(size_t r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
       for(size_t c=0; c<COLS; c++)
           //stuff
}

array<array<int, 2>, 3> arr {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};

f(arr);
```

This works but how? How does the template function figure out the row and col size?  I'm not passing in size info during function call.  I can see how template functions can figure out the type of the object being passed in, but in such a case I don't see how my ROWS and COLS are given values.

This question seeks understanding of this particular case with templates. The question isn't asking about vector or what other data structures exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is *pattern-matching* to make the call work. You're asking about a specific case but I'm not sure where your problem is in understanding so I will illustrate in steps

In the below example, I call `f` with `i` which is an `int`. The compiler deduces that `T = int` to get the call to work.  You might say "how does it know `int` when I haven't passed that type information." but you have, just not explicitly in the template argument list:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
}

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  f(i); // deduces T = int
}
```

To go a step further, the compiler can deduce what T is for two different vector arguments. The calls to `f` below work because the compiler can match the std::vector pattern to the argument I am passing in:

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> v) {
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v1;
  f(v1); // deduces T = int

  std::vector<std::string> v2;
  f(v2); // deduces T = std::string
}
```

In this next example, I create a class that only has one argument, which is a `size_t` and the compiler is still able to match against the `Cls<I>` pattern

```
template <std::size_t N>
class Cls { };

template <std::size_t I>
void f(Cls<I> v) {
}

int main() {
  Cls<3> c1;
  f(c1); // deduces I = 3

  Cls<100> c2;
  f(c2); // deduces I = 100
}
```

The `std::array` version works the same way, there is just another explicit template argument to `std::array` involved:

```
template <std::size_t I>
void f(std::array<int, I> v) {
}

int main() {
  std::array<int, 3> a1;
  f(a1); // deduces I = 3

  std::array<int, 100> a2;
  f(a2); // deduces I = 100
}
```

Impressively, even when there are multiple template arguments nested as your original example, the compiler can **still** look at the argument and match the pattern:

```
template<size_t ROWS, size_t COLS>
void f(std::array<std::array<int, COLS>, ROWS> arr) {
}

int main() {
  std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> arr{};
  f(arr); // deduces COLS = 2 and ROWS = 3 !!
}
```

Adding `const` and `&` in the above examples still works, the pattern is more complex but the compiler can still match it. What a time to be alive!

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  Very clear and detailed.  Amazing indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The size is embedded in the `std::array`.  Because the size is part of `std::array`'s type signature, that information is passed to `f`.  Remember that `std::array<int, 2>` and `std::array<int, 3>` are completely different types that cannot be implicitly converted to each other.

Comment: And similarly, there isn't one copy of the `f` function. There is an `f` specialized for each and every `ROWS` and `COLS` value that the program in question actually uses. Each copy has the value of `ROWS` and the value of `COLS` hardcoded based on the `array` type passed.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mean that the compiler parses "array<array<int, 2>, 3>" to find size_t type compatible values in signature and then assigns them in order to my template func parameters?  If so, in what way, in what order does this happen?  If parsing is left to right, then compiler would find 2 then 3, and the ROWS and COLS would be inverted.  I'm still confused about how the value mapping happens in this case.

Comment: @code - I was going to update my answer, but Ryan Haining said everything I was going to.

Comment: @code: You *gave* the positions names, so the compiler knows the first one is `COLS` and the second `ROWS`.

Comment: ShadowRanger, yes, I see what you mean.  The function signature has the placing and the pattern can be matched with the original instantiation of the array object.

Comment: Thank you Stephen.  No prob.  I'll upvote you anyway.